# Set keyboard layout in Amiga Workbench 3.1

Tags: amiga, amiga-workbench-3.1

I did a fresh install of the Cloanto `amiga-os-310-install.adf` disk to a hard drive, and then I wanted to change the keyboard layout to Swedish. I tried `SYS:System/SetMap s` but then I've learned that `SetMap` was deprecated in Workbench 2. Then I tried `SETKEYBOARD s` which seems to work from a shell, but not when I put it in `S\Startup-Sequence`.

What can I put in `S\Startup-Sequence`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`SETKEYBOARD`](https://wiki.amigaos.net/wiki/AmigaOS_Manual:_AmigaDOS_Command_Reference#SETKEYBOARD) only changes the keyboard layout for the current console (unlike `SETMAP` from older AmigaOS versions, which changes the layout globally), hence running `SETKEYBOARD` from `s/startup-sequence` won't affect other shells than the startup shell itself. Permanent/global keyboard layout changes can be made in `Input Preferences` in `Prefs`, where the language/layout can be selected as `Keyboard Type`. As described in Daedalus' comment below, desired keymaps can be copied to `DEVS:Keymaps` from `Storage`.

Comment: The locale doesn't necessarily have to be installed, but the keymap file does. These are stored on the Storage floppy (or storage drawer of a full hard drive installation), and are activated by moving the desired one to DEVS:Keymaps. Once there, the relevant layout will show up in Prefs/Input. They're independent of Locale settings, which allows you to use a German keyboard for example while the system language is still in English, or vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

I'll add to v-joe's answer that **you should never, ever modify the `Startup-Sequence`**. Since Release 2.0 the `Startup-Sequence` was declared for private use by Commodore, because the system boots in a way to improve compatibility with releases 1.x.

In particular, the combination of `SetPatch` and `IPrefs` enable advanced features that otherwise stay disabled (the most important one is `graphics.library` and `Intuition` to use new fetch modes when running under an AGA machine, but there are other tidbits too). **How the two commands interact was never fully documented, and probably not even tested by Commodore, so adding anything in-between is looking for undefined behavior**.

It's occasionally required to run commands before `SetPatch`, but these are commands that mess with the very low levels of the OS, such as developer's tools, debuggers, commands that play with the MMU, or tools to configure third-party accelerator boards; in this case the command's documentation will explicitly say to add it before `SetPatch`, and you can trust them.

Bottom line: if you need to run DOS commands during the boot, use the `User-Startup` mechanism introduced in Release 2.0: create a file named `User-Startup` inside the `S:` assign (if it is not already there; it usually is) and add your command(s) there. For the record, this is also where `Install` adds commands required by third-party application.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative option to changing the global keyboard layout in `Prefs`, there is a free `SetMap` replacement for Workbench 2.x and 3.x: http://aminet.net/package/util/cli/SetMap.lha (which can change the keymap from the command line and also for all consoles).

To e.g. change the keyboard layout systemwide to Swedish:

```
SetMap s
```

To only change the layout for the current shell (i.e. to have it behave like `SetKeyboard`), `WINDOW` must be specified as a second argument.